# How to clear multiple file upload control single single without changing the another

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three file upload controls and i am uploading 3 different images into all in pop up,

but when i clear the value of single fileupload control it clears the all other also,

so i need a code which clear a single control,

i used Java Script code and c# code also but both behaving same as it clears the all controls,

i tried

**Java script:**

```
function ClearFileUpload1() {
            var fil = document.getElementById("file1");
            fil.select();
            n = fil.createTextRange();
            n.execCommand('delete');
            fil.focus();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the html for the fileupload? Are you using server side controls/html elements?

Comment: i am using  a server control for that,

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="file1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="file1Clear" runat="server" Text="Clear"/><br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="file2" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="file2Clear" runat="server" Text="Clear" /><br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="file3" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="file3Clear" runat="server" Text="Clear"/><br />

Comment: Which asp.net framework are you using, is it >4.0? If yes did you try setting ClientIdMode="Static" on each control and run it?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function fnClearFileSelection(objFileUpload) {
            objFileUpload.value = "";
            objFileUpload.focus();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
Thanks thank you so much as i m using this JS which was sent by s fransis it was working in another page but not my page now as i put ClientIdMode="Static" now its working as i want...

Thank you sir...

Comment: Good to know that it is working now.